# Need guidance on specific bash special parameters

Tags: makefile

My PI wrote a makefile for me to use pandoc, and it makes use of @^ & @<.  For example:

```
%.tex:  %.md
        pandoc -r markdown+$(EXTENSIONS) -s --pdf-engine=$(PDFENGINE) \
        --template=nus-thesis \
        $(FILTERS)  \
        --csl=$(CSL).csl --bibliography=$(BIB) -o $@ $<
```

```
FILE-NAME.md: 00-metadata.yaml \
        01-Introduction.md \
        03-Methods-and-Materials.md \
        04-Results.md \
        05-Discussion.md \
        99-References.md \
        abbrevs.tex \
        11-Supplementary.md
        cat $^ >| $@
```

I have been attempting to look in linux books, bash reference manual, etc, but I have only seen reference to @^ and @< on stack overflow.  Even then, it's used with no description.

Can anyone explain to me what these two parameters are meant to do?

I expect that $^ means all the variables listed earlier, but on @< I'm clueless.

Comment: Those are not bash variables; they are makefile variables. You're looking at the wrong docs.

Comment: @Mat that was the problem...I change my search pattern from bash to make and i found the solution in 5 minutes...Thanks!